# Postgres ilike combined with similarity pg_trgm?

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

I'm experimenting with pg_trgm in my codebase for search. So far it works really well for search queries > 4 characters, which makes sense given how pg_trgm works.

There are however several situations where exact matches aren't returned with queries that are two characters long. For example, looking for a name of 'L2 Kids':

```
SELECT "paid_sessions".* FROM "paid_sessions" WHERE (paid_sessions.name ILIKE '%L2%');
```

Will return the row with the name 'L2 Kids', while the pg_trgrm similarity operator:

```
SELECT "paid_sessions".* FROM "paid_sessions" WHERE (name % 'L2') ORDER BY similarity(name, 'L2') DESC;
```

returns nothing.

How do you handle these exact match deficiency in this case? Should I simply use ilike for searches less than 3 characters? Should I combine the two somehow?

Comment: The `%` operator depends on a threshold that you can set:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#:~:text=show_limit%20()%20%E2%86%92%20real  My strategy would be to use `ilike` in the `where` and `similarity()` in the `order by`.

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce that. I get `TRUE` for `SELECT 'L2 Kids' % 'L2'`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, so something like... `SELECT "paid_sessions".* FROM "paid_sessions" WHERE (paid_sessions.name ILIKE '%L2%') ORDER BY similarity(paid_sessions.name, 'L2') DESC`? 

I think that's exactly what I'm after!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Looks like my similarity match is 0.16 on that and I think I have it set to the default 0.3 still. I'll have a go at tweaking that threshold if I need it in the future. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score -2):

With the default settings, your query using % would return 'L2 kids'. You must have changed the pg_trgm.similarity_threshold in order to not find that result.

> Should I simply use ilike for searches less than 3 characters?

Do you want ILIKE searches?  If so, then you should do that.  Otherwise, you should not.  Maybe you should use `%` but with a different threshold.  Maybe you should use `%>`.  Maybe you want `@@` with tsvectors.  A single example is a poor way of explaining what it is you want.